# How to center text in my navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, center

I try to center my text in my navbar, but it doesn't seem to get right. It currently looks like this:

Mine
[image]

But I want it more like this:
[image]

My navbar looks like this:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse ">
        <div class = "container">
            <div class="navbar-header navbar-text">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Møllaren Café</a>
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>

              <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse">
             <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
                <li class = "active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Meny</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Om oss</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
              </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My css for navbar looks like this:

```
.navbar-text{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;

}
```

This is my custom font:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Diploma Regular';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: local('Diploma Regular'), url('Diploma.woff') format('woff');
}

.navbar-brand{
    font-family: 'Diploma Regular';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Diploma Regular'), url('Diploma.woff') format('woff');
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide all the css you have related to the navbar and its containers? I'm sure there is more.

Comment: @OlivierKrull That is all! I also just have a special font. But I can post that too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this css:

```
.container {
  display : flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

And remove the `navbar-text` styles.

Absolutely not sure if this will work. A working example reproducing your issue would help a lot.

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick for me! Can you explain why? What does the flex mean?

Comment: Also a weird thing. The logo text is now showing over the rest. Why isnt it on the same line as the others?

Answer (score -1):

test with:

```
.container{
    width: 800px;/*adjust*/
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
}
```

then adjust `.container` `width` of the same `width` as `.navbar-text`